# A question in Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ is a real vector space(without topology). call a point $x \in A \subset X$ an internal point of $A$ if $A-x$ is an absorbing set.Suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint convex set in $X$ and $A$ has an internal point.Why there is nonconstant linear funectional $\Gamma $ on $X$ such that $\Gamma (A) \cap \Gamma (B)$ contains at most one point ?(Is this necessary condition that **$A$ has an internal point**)?

Answer (score 0):

separate $A−B$ from $\{ 0\}$.
                                                     .